# how to replace tab to 4 spaces in jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I copied some codes from IDE into jupyter notebook and the indent were done using tab. And there are hundreds of lines with tab indent. how do I replace tabs by 4 spaces easily in jupyter notebook.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Ok, I solved it, under menu of Edit-> Find and Replace, then copy tab sign from jupyter notebook, in the replace input: just use 4 spaces, then replace all.